# Is there a name for a group having a normal subgroup for every divisor of the order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition

Suppose, G is a group of order $n$.

> Is there a name (or an easy criterion) for the property that for every divisor $d|n$, there is a normal subgroup of order $d$ ?

The abelian groups and the p-groups have this property, but other groups satisfy the property as well. The dihedral groups (excluding the 2-groups) do not have this property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, these are precisely the finite **nilpotent groups**.

This is because a finite group is nilpotent if and only if it has a unique - that is, normal - Sylow $p$-subgroup for each prime divisor $p$ of its order. And thus, the finite nilpotent groups are exactly the direct products of groups of prime-power order.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop the condition on the normality of the subgroups, then this class of groups is called *CLT groups* (satifiying the *C*onverse of *L*agrange's *T*heorem). There is a classic paper of [Henry Bray](http://msp.org/pjm/1968/27-2/pjm-v27-n2-p02-p.pdf) that provides the basic properties of these groups. We have the following proper inclusions of classes $$\{Nilpotent \text{ } Groups\} \subsetneq \{Supersolvable \text{ } Groups\} \subsetneq\{CLT \text{ } Groups\} \subsetneq \{Solvable \text{ } Groups\}.$$
CLT groups are neither subgroup- nor quotient-closed, but a finite direct product of CLT groups is again CLT.