# Let G be group of order $125$. Will it have a subgroup of order $25$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $125$. Does it have a subgroup of order $25$ ? For any abelian group, the answer is yes. But what about non-abelian groups? I cannot understand. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Every group of prime power order $p^n$ has subgroups of each order $p^m$ for integer $0\le m\le n$.

Comment: Yes,It is Sylow's first theorem.

Comment: Can u write a rigorous answer? I would accept ur answer..@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Hiiii @Lord Shark the Unknown  where did you get this statement? Can you please share a link so that I can read the proof?

Comment: See egreg's answer.

Comment: Was that Sylow's First theorem?@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Was that Sylow's First theorem?@Muse_China

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “big property” you need is that a group of order $p^n$ ($p$ a prime, $n>0$) has a non trivial center. This is one of the most important facts about $p$-groups.

The proof of the fact is a consequence of the [*conjugacy class equation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation).

Once you accept it, it's quite simple to prove the following proposition.

> Let $G$ be a $p$-group of order $p^n$. If $0\le k<n$, then there exists a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$.

*Proof.* The case $n=1$ is obvious. So let's assume the statement holds for every $p$-group of order $p^{n-1}$, with $n>1$.

By the fact mentioned above, $|Z(G)|=p^z$, with $z>0$, so it has a subgroup $Z_0$ of order $p$ which is obviously normal in $G$.

There is nothing to prove for $k=0$, so assume $0<k<n$. Since $G/Z_0$ has order $p^{n-1}$, by induction hypothesis it has a subgroup $H/Z_0$ of order $p^{k-1}$. Therefore $|H|=p^k$. QED

Answer (score 6):

**Sylow's First Theorem:** Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime. Then for each $p^k$ dividing $|G|$, $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$.

From this it directly follows that, $G$ has subgroups of order $5$ and $5^2=25$.

I would also want you to note the following observations and prove the following results as a handy exercise.

**Result-1:** The center of a Group is never a maximal subgroup.

**Result-2:** If $|G|=p^k$, where $p$ is prime then $G$ has a non-trivial center.

From the above results, we can go on to say that $|Z(G)|=5$.

Comment: hiii @Naïve  where did you get this theorem - Sylow's First Theorem?

Comment: What Was  Sylow's First theorem's proof? Can u please explain?@Naive

Answer (score 2):

Groups with order a power of a prime (i.e. $p$-groups) have the

> Property: have a **normal** subgroup of order $d$ for every $d$ that divides the order of the group.

This is not a coincidence, indeed a finite $p$-group is **nilpotent** and finite nilpotent groups are characterized by the above property (remember that finite nilpotent groups are direct product of their $p$-Sylow subgroups). This is no longer true if we relax nilpotency to solvability ($S_3$ with $p=2$).
If we do not care about normality, we may ask whether a group $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$ for every $d$ that divides $|G|$. This called CLT property (i.e. Converse of the Lagrange Theorem) that has been extensively studied. For this topic, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686965/is-there-a-name-for-a-group-having-a-normal-subgroup-for-every-divisor-of-the-or) question is relevant. In particular, a minimal normal subgroup of a supersolvable group must have prime order and by induction on the quotient you can show that "supersolvable" $\implies$ CLT. Finally a group $G$ that is CLT, in particular, has a $p$-complement (i.e. a subgroup with index equal the order of a $p$-Sylow) for every $p$ prime that divides $|G|$, and is solvable by [the converse of the Hall's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup#A_converse_to_Hall.27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete variant of @egreg's answer, using the key fact that $Z(G)$ is not trivial.

If there is an element of order $125$ or $25$, then we're done.

Otherwise, all elements have order $1$ or $5$.

Let $a\in Z(G)$ with $a\ne e$ and $b \in G$ with $b\notin \langle a \rangle$.

Then the set of products $a^i b^j$ is a subgroup of order $25$.

Comment: I wish I could avoid using that $Z(G)$ is not trivial.