# When we can say a group can not be abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order $125$. Which of the following statements are necessarily true?
>
> 1. $G$ has a non-trivial abelian subgroup.
> 2. The centre of $G$ is a proper subgroup.
> 3. The centre of $G$ has order $5$.
> 4. There is a subgroup of order $25$.

**Solution(Partial):**

1. Since $G$ has a subgroup of order $5$, $G$ has a non-trivial abelian subgroup. Hence (1) is true.
2. (*)I think (2) is not true, since $G$ can be abelian, then centre may not be proper subgroup.
3. Since (2) is not true it is not necessary to be centre of order $5$. Hence (3) is not true.
4. (4) is true for the fact that $125=5\times 25$.  Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329356/let-g-be-group-of-order-125-will-it-have-a-subgroup-of-order-25).

---

I think I need better explanation for (*). More generally is there any **specific way to argue that** ---- $\color{red}{\text{When we can say a group can not be abelian if we only know the order of the group?}}$

Comment: Yes you are right .Consider  $\frac {Z}{125Z}$. In your question they didn't specify about group except it's order that's why you can take abelian as well as non abelian groups to discard options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your main question, i.e.

> When we can say a group can not be abelian if we only know the order of the group?

is **never**. For every $n$, there exists an Abelian group of order $n$, that group is $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: that is what exactly I was thinking!, thanks for clearing my doubt!

Answer (score 3):

Never.

There is always $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: that is what exactly I was thinking!, thanks for clearing my doubt!