# Let $G$ be a group of order $125$. Then which of the following statements are necessarily true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $125$. Then which of the following statements are necessarily true?

A) $G$ has a non-trivial abelian subgroup
B) the center of $G$ is proper subgroup
C) center of $G$ has exactly $5$ elements
D) there is a subgroup of order $25$

My attempt:
Since $5$ is a prime number and order of $g$ is $5^3$ so center of $G$ has exactly $5$ elements. So options A, B, C are correct.

Comment: tURN OFF YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY

Comment: If $G$ is abelian, then of course we see that B and C are false.

Comment: yes if G is abelian group then its center G=Z,so option a,b,c does not hold..but when G is non-abelian group then option a,b,c are hold,,But in question there have mention nothing whether G is abelian or non-abelian group..so what am I do?

Comment: @Halima.Khatun Do you know the meaning of "necessarily true"?

Comment: no..I have not clear concept..plz help me

Comment: Ha Ha...I posted [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380926/when-we-can-say-a-group-can-not-be-abelian) yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

B) and C) are true only when $G$ is non-Abelian.

D) follows from Sylow's theorem

By D), A) is also true